# Passing a variable to determine connection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a way where i can pass a value like a bucket name and then use that to populate a value in my method in a class. I have a controller which is a class which establishes two connection, one is called bucket, the other bucket2. Both methods are identical except one uses bucket the other bucket2. I want to avoid creating dual methods and use a variable to decide which bucket the method is using.

Below is my controller class

```
const couchbase = require("couchbase")
const config = require("../config/config")

class CouchController {
    constructor() {
        this.cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config.cluster);
        this.cluster.authenticate(config.userid, config.password)
        this.N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;

        this.bucket = this.cluster.openBucket('Contacts', function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Got error: %j', err);
            }
        });
        this.bucket2 = this.cluster.openBucket('mail_store', function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Got error: %j', err);
            }
        });

    }
    getDoc(docID) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.bucket.get(docID, (err, result) => {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                return resolve({ docID, result });
            });
        });
    }
    getDoc2(docID) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.bucket2.get(docID, (err, result) => {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                return resolve({ docID, result });
            });
        });
    }
}
module.exports = CouchController
```

i took a stab at it and came up with a working solution but its not clean as i would like

```
getDoc(bucket, docID) {
    if (bucket == "bucket2") {
        bucket = this.bucket2
    } else {
        bucket = this.bucket
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bucket.get(docID, (err, result) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve({ docID, result });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I would like to see some code that calls `getDoc` to see how you're going to use that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'd "map" bucket objects to bucket names...

```
bucketWithName(name) {
    let buckets = { bucket2: this.bucket2, ... others here ...}
    return buckets[name] || this.bucket // this.bucket is default
}

getDoc(bucketName, docID) {
    let bucket = this.bucketWithName(bucketName);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bucket.get(docID, (err, result) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve({ docID, result });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok i found the issue, you have a typo in your code, should be 
let bucket = this.bucketWithName(bucketName);

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution would be to pass the bucket as a parameter rather than use a variable to decide which variable to use. See as an example :

```js
getDoc(bucket, docID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bucket.get(docID, (err, result) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve({ docID, result });
        });
    });
}
```

and call it with
`this.getDoc(this.bucket, some_id);` if you need to use bucket in this context or use `this.getDoc(this.bucket2, some_id);` if you need to use bucket2 in this context.

I hope it helps !